How do you get video to connect to the GPU and not the motherboard?
On my new desktop computer, there are 5 DisplayPorts, 3 of which connect to the motherboard and 2 of which connect to the discrete GPU. However, the 2 DisplayPorts on the GPU do not output any signal when I use Ubuntu. Instead, the video comes out of the motherboard DisplayPorts. This is not true of the BIOS, my Windows installation on the same computer, or even the GRUB bootloader (that works perfectly fine for some reason). All of those output video from the GPU just fine. This is very frustrating because Windows is the exact opposite of Linux: it only outputs video out of the GPU and not the motherboard. So I have to physically switch which port my cable is plugged into whenever I go between Windows and Linux. It would be best if the video could come out of the GPU at all times.
Details about the current situation and what I've tried:

As far as I'm aware, the graphics card seems to be working fine even though no video is coming out of there. I have run graphics benchmarks on both Linux and Windows, and both of them achieve a similar level of performance that I'm fairly certain integrated graphics could not have achieved.
I am dual-booting Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and Windows 11
I have tried installing Pop OS instead of Ubuntu, but that didn't fix the issue.
The computer is a Dell Precision 3460. It is new, so I haven't tinkered with it too much.
The graphics card is an AMD Radeon Pro W6300
I have disabled fast boot in Windows and secure boot in the BIOS
In the BIOS, there is a setting labeled "Primary Display" with 3 options: "Auto", "Onboard Video", and "AMD HD Graphics (slot 1)". I changed the setting from Auto to "AMD HD Graphics (slot 1)" and also updated the BIOS to the latest version from the Dell website, but that didn't fix the issue. I did not see any other settings pertaining to the graphics card in the BIOS.
Besides the 5 DisplayPorts, there are no other DisplayPorts, HDMI ports, VGA ports, or any other kind of video output port.
The manual for my computer says that I should plug the DisplayPort into the GPU

Here is the output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display':
0000:00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Dell AlderLake-S GT1
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, xe
--
0000:03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 24 [Radeon PRO W6300/W6300M] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Navi 24 [Radeon PRO W6300/W6300M]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

And the output of lspci:
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4640 (rev 02)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
0000:00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 XHCI Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH Shared SRAM (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH HECI Controller #1 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aeb (rev 11)
0000:00:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a88 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SPI Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-LM (rev 11)
0000:01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 01)
0000:02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch
0000:03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 24 [Radeon PRO W6300/W6300M] (rev 01)
0000:03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
10000:e0:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 11)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9B1 (DRAM-less) (rev 02)

